# How to write bytes to a file in Python 3 without knowing the encoding?

Tags: python, io, python-3.x

In Python 2.x with 'file-like' object:

```
sys.stdout.write(bytes_)
tempfile.TemporaryFile().write(bytes_)
open('filename', 'wb').write(bytes_)
StringIO().write(bytes_)
```

How to do the same in Python 3?

How to write equivalent of this Python 2.x code:

```
def write(file_, bytes_):
    file_.write(bytes_)
```

Note: `sys.stdout` is not always semantically a text stream. It might be beneficial to consider it as a stream of bytes sometimes. For example, [make encrypted archive of dir/ on remote machine](http://www.pixelbeat.org/cmdline.html):

```
tar -c dir/ | gzip | gpg -c | ssh user@remote 'dd of=dir.tar.gz.gpg'
```

There is no point to use Unicode in this case.

Answer (score 75, accepted):

It's a matter of using APIs that operate on bytes, rather than strings.

```
sys.stdout.buffer.write(bytes_)
```

As the [docs](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/sys.html#sys.stdin) explain, you can also `detach` the streams, so they're binary by default.

This accesses the underlying byte buffer.

```
tempfile.TemporaryFile().write(bytes_)
```

This is already a byte API.

```
open('filename', 'wb').write(bytes_)
```

As you would expect from the 'b', this is a byte API.

```
from io import BytesIO
BytesIO().write(bytes_)
```

`BytesIO` is the byte equivalent to `StringIO`.

EDIT: `write` will Just Work on any *binary* file-like object.  So the general solution is just to find the right API.

Comment: Is there a way to write general function without resorting to type checking such as `isinstance(file_, io.TextIOWrapper)`, etc.

Comment: @J.F., Python 3 is designed specifically to handle the text v. binary divide properly.  Without knowing the encoding, there is no correct way to go between binary and text.  So there's no way to write a general function that writes bytes to a text stream.  Dive Into Python 3 has a good [article](http://diveintopython3.org/strings.html) on this.

Comment: The question is specifically about *bytes*. For example, `os.write(sys.stdout.fileno(), bytes_)`.

Comment: So the answer is: pass an object whose '.write()' method accepts bytes; there are no shortcuts.

Comment: @MatthewFlaschen : 
Showing error `NameError: name 'bytes_' is not defined`, When `open('filename', 'wb').write(bytes_)`

Comment: @AayushKumarSingha: `bytes_` is your data e.g., `bytes_ = b'\x89PNG\r\n\x1a\n'`

Answer (score 33):

Specify binary mode, 'b', when you open your file:

```
with open('myfile.txt', 'wb') as w:
    w.write(bytes)
```

https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html#open