# Print without b' prefix for bytes in Python 3

Tags: python, string, python-3.x

How do I print a `bytes` string without the `b'` prefix in Python 3?

```
>>> print(b'hello')
b'hello'
```

Comment: related: [How to write bytes to a file in Python 3 without knowing the encoding?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4290716/4279)

Answer (score 179):

Use `decode`:

```
>>> print(b'hello'.decode())
hello
```

Comment: @ShubhamA. The default value of the `encoding` parameter when not set is indeed `'utf-8'`: https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#bytes.decode

Answer (score 30):

If the bytes use an appropriate character encoding already; you could print them directly:

```
sys.stdout.buffer.write(data)
```

or

```
nwritten = os.write(sys.stdout.fileno(), data)  # NOTE: it may write less than len(data) bytes
```

Answer (score 27):

According to the source for [`bytes.__repr__`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/692e9078a10b268530f8da7d3095cfb05c48435b/Objects/bytesobject.c#L1282-L1355), the `b''` is baked into the method.

One workaround is to manually slice off the `b''` from the resulting `repr()`:

```
>>> x = b'\x01\x02\x03\x04'

>>> print(repr(x))
b'\x01\x02\x03\x04'

>>> print(repr(x)[2:-1])
\x01\x02\x03\x04
```

Comment: Side note: I don't think any of the other answers *truly* answer the question.

Comment: I think I would agree: your solution, namely `repr(x)[2:-1]`, produces a `str` object that will print as wish.  In particular, `repr(b'\x01')[2:-1]` returns the string `\\x01`, while `decode()` will return `\x01` which does not work as one would wish with `print()`.  To be even more explicit, `print(repr(b'\x01')[2:-1])` will print `\x01` while `print(b'\x01'.decode())` will not print anything.

Comment: Alternatively, ```print(repr(b"\x01".decode()))```will print `'\x01'` (a string including the single quotes ), so that ```print(repr(b"\x01".decode())[1:-1])``` prints `\x01` (a string without the single quotes ).

Comment: I was hoping to rid of endless x.encode x.decode nonsense forever in py3 but still need this repr(x)[2:-1] stuff when dealing with encrypted data from py2 in py3... Sad...

Comment: The note that this is because of `bytes.__repr__` is great, but the recommendation of `print(repr(x)[2:-1])` is pretty darn ugly! Not a fan of the proposed solution, although this answer is very educational.

Answer (score 26):

If the data is in an UTF-8 compatible format, you can convert the bytes to a string.

```
>>> print(str(b"hello", "utf-8"))
hello
```

Optionally, convert to hex first if the data is not UTF-8 compatible (e.g. data is raw bytes).

```
>>> from binascii import hexlify
>>> print(hexlify(b"\x13\x37"))
b'1337'
>>> print(str(hexlify(b"\x13\x37"), "utf-8"))
1337
```

```
>>> from codecs import encode  # alternative
>>> print(str(encode(b"\x13\x37", "hex"), "utf-8"))
1337
```

Answer (score 10):

To show or print:

```
<byte_object>.decode("utf-8")
```

To encode or save:

```
<str_object>.encode('utf-8')
```

Answer (score 4):

I am a little late but for Python 3.9.1 this worked for me and removed the -b prefix:

```
print(outputCode.decode())
```

Answer (score 1):

It's so simple...
(With that, you can encode the dictionary and list bytes, then you can stringify it using json.dump / json.dumps)

You just need use base64

```py
import base64

data = b"Hello world!" # Bytes
data = base64.b64encode(data).decode() # Returns a base64 string, which can be decoded without error.
print(data)
```

There are bytes that cannot be decoded by default(pictures are an example), so base64 will encode those bytes into bytes that can be decoded to string, to retrieve the bytes just use

```py
data = base64.b64decode(data.encode())
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `decode()` instead of `encode()` for converting bytes to a string.

```
>>> import curses
>>> print(curses.version.decode())
2.2
```

Answer (score 0):

i know this has been answered but

```
encoded = str(encoded).replace('b', '', 1)
```